# How to show pseudo r-squared using esttab?

Tags: stata

I tried to export logit regression results to an Excel file. I used `eststo` to save the results and then I used the following command:

```
esttab using C:\Users\Ahn\Desktop\tt.csv, pr2
```

In the Excel file, it shows **coefficients**, **t-stats**, and etc, but **pseudo r-squared** has blanks. When I tried the following command, `esttab` still doesn't show the values of pseudo r-squared:

```
esttab, pr2
```

Is there any way to show pseudo r-squared in the Excel file?

Answer (score 2):

I can't repoduce your problem. After running

```
clear
set more off

webuse lbw

logit low age lwt i.race smoke ptl ht ui
esttab using ~/Desktop/stata_tests/logtest.csv, pr2
```

the .csv file reads:

[image]

I'm on Stata 12.1 and `esttab` (part of the ESTOUT module from SSC) has version

```
. which estout
/home/roberto/ado/plus/e/estout.ado
*! version 3.17  02jun2014  Ben Jann
```

Update, if you can.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, it is difficult to show the number of observations and pseudo r in the same table. But if you use

```
esttab, pr2
```

in the end of the table it is the pseudo r and the N.